# DELETE method in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to DELETE record in Django Rest.

views.py :-

```
class ItemPartialView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = itemlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemlistSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj.survey:
            return Response(data={'message': "Too late to delete"},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.perform_destroy(obj)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^itemlists/$', ItemView.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r'^itemlists/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ItemPartialUpdateView.as_view(), name="update")

}
```

Now, when I am sending DELETE request to `itemlists/1/` , it is not deleting the record with `id = 1`
Error is showing `Method DELETE not allowed`

(CREATE, READ, UPDATE are working except DELETE, so I don't think it's cors related issue).

Comment: Why is your function named `destroy()` instead of `delete()`?

Comment: delete() is resulting the same

Comment: Is `delete()` a member of the `ItemPartialView` class?  i.e. is the function indented underneath the class?  In the question, it isn't.

Comment: It was my edit mistake. Updated code.

Comment: You could use viewsets: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset
And routers: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė I already proposed this in his pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852845/get-request-with-request-parameter-in-django-rest-framework/47856583#47856583). Imho the right way to go.

Comment: Send your  DELETE request to itemlists/1/delete

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 routes defined for `itemlists/1/`. Your code is hitting the first one which only has partial update (PUT/PATCH) support judging from the name.

You should create one view with both update and destroy on the same class. That should work.

Comment: Updated the views, please check.

Comment: The method is called `update`, not `put`. Please consult the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it - you don't use your `ItemPartialView` in your urls.

You use `ItemPartialUpdateView` instead, so my guess is that delete is not supported with this view.