# GET request with request parameter in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to do GET with a request parameter in Django Rest.

views.py :-

```
class ItemView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = itemlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        serializer.save()

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = itemlist.objects.all()

        get_param = self.request.GET.get('get_param')
        if get_param:
            queryset = queryset.filter(item_name=get_param)

        return queryset
```

urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = {

    url(r'^itemlists/$', ItemView.as_view(), name="itemlist")
}
```

`itemlists/` returns the list of all items. But, I want to return for a particular item, where let's say, `item_name = "abcd"`
URL will look like, `itemlists/abcd/`

I tried with,

```
urlpatterns = {

    url(r'^itemlists/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ItemView.as_view(), name="itemlist")
}
```

Comment: Can you please search for DetailView. I hope that will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to keep it plain and simple, django rest framework provides this functionality right out of the Box (ish). In order to get it working, you'll need to edit your code a little bit.

Django rest framework provides so called `viewsets`, which provide `CRUD` operation endpoints right out of the box. What's more, by subclassing `rest_framework.generics.GenericViewSet` and selectively adding so called mixins, we can limit the operations we want to provide for this endpoint.

In order to achieve your desired functionality, we will

- Implement a custom viewset, which provides `list`, `create` and `retrieve` functionality
- Implement a `SimpleRouter` which takes care of the routing for us and include it in our root url conf.

#### In your view.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import (RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin)

class ItemViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    queryset = itemlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
    lookup_field = 'item_name'
```

What's going on here? While `GenericViewSet` gives us a startingpoint, django rest framework's `mixins` enables us to selectively throw in actions we want to implement, i.e. `retrieve` ("detail view"), `list` and so on. For more info, check [this link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins).
By throwing in `RetrieveModelMixin`, `CreateModelMixin` and `ListModelMixin`, we have created a viewset with your desired functionality. Awesome right?

Out of the box, the `RetrieveModelMixin` dealing with instance-level lookups performs the query based on the `pk` attribute. In order to change it, we override the `lookup_field` attribute to `'item_name'`. Once we've done this, your custom viewset is ready to go. Next, we'll use django rest framework's `SimpleRouter` to automagically include all our viewset's routes for us.

#### In your urls.py

Simply pass your view to a Router during instantiation and include it in your url conf. Note that urlconf is a `list` and has brackets, not curly braces (as in your question).

```
from rest_framework import routers
from somwhere.views import ItemViewSet
# ...
router = router.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'itemlist', ItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # ... other stuff
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

#### Limitations

The `CreateModelMixin` does not create a new model instance, but delegates this task to the serializer set in `serializer_class`. That is, to get the above code to work, you either need to use a `ModelSerializer`, what judging from the name `ItemSerializer` you're already doing or implement your custom creation logic. This can either happen in your custom viewset by overriding the `create` method in your `ItemViewSet` class or by implementing `create` on your serializer.

Cheers,
D

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. What should be my URL here ?

Comment: I mean, the GET call url

Comment: If `urls.py` is your root conf, your list endpoint is `{host}/itemlist/`, your Detail view is `{Host}/itemlist/{item_name}/`

Comment: It is not resulting the view of that particular {item_name} , instead it is showing all the items, that is itemlist/

Comment: Can you paste your code in your question? I tried the code before submitting my answer and it works for me.

Comment: Also, did you remove the other `itemlist` patterns you implemented previously? Otherwise, it is possible that you match these before even reaching the viewset.

Comment: I removed it from the other itemlist. Thanks, approved the answer.